# How to update detailViewController.detailItem from multi-level nav in rootViewController

Tags: xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

this is my first post so please be gently.

I am using the basic Split View-based application within xcode, but have edited it so that the rootViewController does not simply update the detailViewController, but instead pushes a new UITableViewController (taskViewController) onto the navigation stack.

My problem is, that nothing happens when I now call the following from my taskViewController:

```
detailViewController.detailItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", indexPath.row];
```

If I call this from rootViewController, instead of pushing a new UITableView onto the stack, it works.

Here is my code from rootViewController when a cell is selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TaskViewController *taskViewController = [[TaskViewController alloc] init];

    taskViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unit %d",indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:taskViewController animated:YES];

    [taskViewController release];
}
```

Have I done something wrong here?  Am I using the navigation controller correctly within the rootViewController of the UISplitViewController?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rootViewController can access detailViewController because it has a referance to it. if you push a new controller onto the nav stack, then its **not** automatically going to know about DetailViewController.

Have you `NSLog`'d `detailViewController` in your taskVC to see if it has a pointer?

You would typically set this when you are creating it like this:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        TaskViewController *taskViewController = [[TaskViewController alloc] init];

        taskViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unit %d",indexPath.row];

        taskViewController.detailViewController = self.detailViewController;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:taskViewController animated:YES];

        [taskViewController release];
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic!  I just assumed that the UISplitViewController took care of all of this.  Thank you

Comment: It did, as far as the basic root and detail VC's, but after that your on your own- dw, it's a common mistake when your starting out. I should warn you though, splitViewControllers have other issues too, I will let you take that journey yourself though. `NSLog` is your friend.